# Sorting a list with group by - List has codes starting with numbers

Tags: java, sorting, java-8

I am trying to sort a list which has used group by. THe list has codes which start with numbers. One of the option is Not Applicable. I want "Not Applicable" to be at bottom.

```
    Flux.fromIterable(containers)
                .map(containerTypeMapper::containerTypeDto)
                .groupBy(ContainerTypeDto::getCategory)
                .flatMap(idFlux -> idFlux.collectList().map(listContainers -> new    ContainerDto(idFlux.key(),listContainers)));
```

I want "Not Applicabe" option at the bottom for each container type. Not applicable is name in containertypedto.

And rest of the names in the list are - "40 xxxx xxx"t, "40 Open Top", "45 Pallet Wide"

Comment: Please edit the question to limit it to a specific problem with enough detail to identify an adequate answer.

Comment: This is a guideline to how you can improve your question to get more answers: [How do I ask a good question?](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask). I hope it helps :)